# Is it possible to remove the following !$OMP CRITICAL regions

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, openmp

I have a fortran code that shows some very unsatisfactory performance due to some $OMP CRITICAL regions. This question is actually more about how to the critical regions can be avoided and whether those regions can be removed? In those critical regions I am updating counters and reading/writing values to an array

```
    i=0
    j=MAX/2
    total = 0

    !$OMP PARALLEL PRIVATE(x,N)

    MAIN_LOOP:do
    $OMP CRITICAL
        total = total + 1
        x = array(i)
        i = i + 1
        if ( i > MAX) i=1 ! if the counter is past the end start form the beginning 
    $OMP END CRITICAL
        if (total > MAX_TOTAL) exit

    ! do some calculations here and get the value of the integer (N)
    ! store (N) copies of x it back in the original array with some offset

    !$OMP CRITICAL
    do p=1,N
    array(j)=x
    j=j+1
    if (j>MAX) j=1
    end do
    !$OMP END CRITICAL

 end do MAIN_LOOP
 $OMP END PARALLEL
```

One simple thing that came to my mind is to eliminate the counter on `total` by using explicit dynamic loop scheduling.

```
!$OMP PARALLEL DO SCHEDULE(DYNAMIC) 
MAIN_LOOP:do total = 1,MAX_TOTAL
  ! do the calculation here
end do MAIN_LOOP
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO
```

I was also thinking to allocate different portion of the `array` to each thread and using the thread `ID` to do offsetting. This time each processor will have it's own counter which will be stored in an array `count_i(ID)` and something of the sort

```
!this time the size if array is NUM_OMP_THREADS*MAX
   x=array(ID + sum(count_i)) ! get the offset by summing up all values
   ID=omp_get_thread_num()
   count_i(ID)=count_i(ID)+1
if (count_i(ID) > MAX) count_i(ID) = 1
```

This however will mess the order and will not do the same as the original method. Moreover some empty space will be present, since the different threads will not able to fit the entire range `1:MAX`

I would appreciate your help and ideas.

Comment: I don't know that you can call exit inside of an OpenMP region...

Comment: What is `MAX_TOTAL` here, and how does it compare to the `size(array)` and `MAX`?

Comment: `MAX_TOTAL` is the number of iterations the loop `MAIN_LOOP:do` is supposed to do. it is the same as `do total=1,MAX_TOTAL`

Comment: Alexander Cska: So the code could end up making more or less than one pass through the array, then?

Comment: I'm really not sure that what your code actually does is what you want or think it does: in your snippet, `x` is shared and updated by all threads in sequence (one after the other in no particular order). So you just don't know what value it has, but you use it to compute, knowing it can change at any moment behind your back as yet another thread reaches the `critical` section... What's the meaning of that?

Comment: Since it is just a snippet, I forgot to declare `PRIVATE(x)`. The critical region is mainly due to the array and counters update. Think about it this way, what will happen if I removed the `CRITICAL` clause. Since the counters are shared there would be a data race. I can't declare them `PRIVATE` or `THREADPRIVATE` and I can't use  `REDUCTION` either, since I need the updated values inside the main loop.

Comment: Well `p` does not really matter, since it is updated inside a `CRITICAL` region one thread at a time. Only if you removed the `CRITICAL` it should be declared private

Answer (score 2):

Your use of critical sections is a bit strange here. The motivation for using critical sections must be to avoid having an entry in the array being clobbered before it can be read. Your code does accomplish this, but only accidentally, by acting as barriers. Try replacing the critical stuff with OMP barriers, and you should still get the right result and the same horrible speed.

Since you always write to the array half its length away from where you write to it, you can avoid critical sections by dividing the operation into one step which reads from the first half and writes to the second half, and vice versa. (**Edit: After the question was edited, this is no longer true, so the approach below won't work**).

```
nhalf = size(array)/2
!$omp parallel do
do i = 1, nhalf
    array(i+nhalf) = f(array(i))
end do
!$omp parallel do
do i = 1, nhalf
    array(i) = f(array(i+nhalf))
end do
```

Here `f(x)` represents whatever calculation you want to do to the array values. It doesn't have to be a function if you don't want it to. If it isn't clear, this code first loops through the entries in the first half of the array in parallel. The first task may go through i=1,1+nproc,1+2*nproc, etc. while the second task goes through i=2,2+nproc,2+2*nproc, and so on. This can be done in parallel without any locking because there is no overlap between the part of the array that is read from and written to in this loop. The second loop only starts once every task has finished the first loop, so there is no clobbering between the loops.

Unlike in your code, there is here one `i` per thread, so one doesn't need locking to update it (the loop variable is automatically private).

This assumes that you only want to make one pass through the array. Otherwise you can just loop over these two loops:

```
do iouter = 1, (max_total+size(array)-1)/size(array)
    nleft = max_total-(iouter-1)*size(array)
    nhalf = size(array)/2
    !$omp parallel do
    do i = 1, min(nhalf,nleft)
        array(i+nhalf) = f(array(i))
    end do
    !$omp parallel do
    do i = 1, min(nhalf,nleft-nhalf)
        array(i) = f(array(i+nhalf))
    end do
end do
```

Edit: Your new example is confusing. I'm not sure what it's supposed to do. Depending on the value of `N`, the array values may end being clobbered before they can be used. Is this intentional? It's hard to answer your question when it's not clear what you're trying to do. :/

Comment: This would not work, because the main loop and the array offset indexes are not linearly linked. I am producing many `i` and `j` values within one cycle of the main loop. The critical region is so that no two threads write at the same position

Comment: I don't see what you mean. There is no looping in any of the critical sections as far as I can see. Perhaps this will be easier if you can write a minimal test case that I can compile and run, along with the expected output?

Comment: Please check the edit. I can generate few `j` values per one cycle of the main loop. I didn't include the nested loop, because I was thinking that this will make the problem more complicated to understand. Now I see that it might be misleading. Things are not so simple unfortunately.

Comment: How large can `N` be? Is `N` a constant? A minimal example I could compile and run would be very appreciated. If `N` is too large, then your critical sections do not save you from clobbering the input values before they can be used.

Comment: Well it is very difficult to write an example because we are speaking about a massive code here. Basically, I am looking at particles leaving a geometry and N represents this number. How many times the main do loop writes N values is determined by a stochastic process. I can tell you that simple solution won't work here, actually I am not sure that this can be done at all.

Answer (score 1):

I thought about this for a while and my feeling is that there is no good answer to this specific issue.

Indeed, your code seems, at first glance, like a good approach to the problem such as stated (although I personally find the problem itself a bit strange). However, there are problems in your implementation:

- What happens if for some reason one of the threads gets delayed in processing its iteration? Just imagine that the thread *owning* very first index takes a while to process it (delayed y some third party process coming in the way and taking the CPU time on the core where the thread was pinned/scheduled for example) and is the last to finish... Then it will set back its values to `array` in a completely different order than what the sequential algorithm would have done. Is that something you can accept in your algorithm?
- Even without this sort of "extreme" delay, can you accept that the order in which the `i` indexes were distributed among threads is different that the order in which the `j` indexes are subsequently updated? If the thread owning `i+1` finishes right before the one owning `i`, it will use index `j` instead of index `j+n` as it should have had...

Again, I'm not sure I understand all the subtleties of your algorithm and how resilient it is to miss-ordering of iterations, but if ordering is something important, then the approach is wrong. In this case, I guess that a proper parallelisation could be something like this (put in a subroutine to make it compilable):

```
subroutine loop(array, maxi, max_iteration)
    implicit none
    integer, intent(in) :: maxi, max_iteration
    real, intent(inout) :: array(maxi)
    real :: x
    integer :: iteration, i, j, n, p

    i = 0
    j = maxi/2
    !$omp parallel do ordered private(x, n, p) schedule(static,1)
    do iteration = 1,max_iteration
        !$omp ordered
        x = array(wrap_around(i, maxi))
        !$omp end ordered

        ! do some calculations here and get the value of the integer (n)

        !$omp ordered
        do p = 1,n
           array(wrap_around(j, maxi)) = x
        end do
        !$omp end ordered
    end do
    !$omp end parallel do 
contains
    integer function wrap_around(i, maxi)
        implicit none
        integer, intent(in)    :: maxi
        integer, intent(inout) :: i

        i = i+1
        if (i > maxi) i = 1
        wrap_around = i
    end function wrap_around
end subroutine loop
```

I hope this would work. However, unless the central part of the loop where `n` is retrieved does some serious computation, this won't be any faster than the sequential version.